# What are the meanings of the "~" and "&=" symbols in python?

Tags: python, notation

I saw the following in a python group:

```
>> bookStyle = aui.AUI_NB_DEFAULT_STYLE
>> bookStyle &= ~(aui.AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ACTIVE_TAB)
```

Could you explain the second statement?? What does `&=` and `~` do?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: @C.B.'s link explains it better than all the answers combined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [bitwise operators documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations),

> The unary `~` (invert) operator yields the bitwise inversion of its plain or long integer argument. The bitwise inversion of x is defined as -(x+1). It only applies to integral numbers.

`&=` can be understood like this

```
bookStyle = bookStyle & ~(aui.AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ACTIVE_TAB)
```

So, we basically, invert the value of `aui.AUI_NB_CLOSE_ON_ACTIVE_TAB` and then check if all the ON bits in the inverted value are ON in `bookStyle` as well.

The `~` can be understood better with 32 bit arithmetic like this

`5` can be represented in 32 bit Binary like this

```
print format(5 & (1 << 32) - 1, "032b")
# 00000000000000000000000000000101
```

Now, when we do `~5` result will be

```
print ~5
# -6
```

So, lets print `-6` in Binary

```
print format(-6 & (1 << 32) - 1, "032b")
# 11111111111111111111111111111010
```

If we compare the values,

```
00000000000000000000000000000101
11111111111111111111111111111010
```

you get the idea what exactly is happening internally.

Answer (score 0):

Those are [bitwise operators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

> **x & y** Does a "bitwise and".
>
> **~ x** Returns the complement of x - the number you get by switching each 1 for a 0 and each 0 for a 1.

Answer (score 0):

`~x` is a unary operator equivalent to `(-x)-1` for numbers.

```
x &= y
```

is equivalent to

```
x = x & y
```

where `&` stands for binary and.

Answer (score 0):

`~` is a binary invertion operator.

`bob &= lucy` is shorter version of `bob = bob & lucy`. Basically, bitwise `AND` and store results value.

More about that - [Unary arithmetics and bitwise operations @Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations)

Answer (score 0):

(~) : Binary Ones Complement Operator is unary and has the efect of 'flipping' bits

For Example:

```
a = 0011 1100
(~a ) will give -61 which is 1100 0011 in 2's complement form due to a signed binary  number
```

(&) : Binary AND Operator copies a bit to the result if it exists in both operands.

```
a = 0011 1100
b = 0000 1101
(a & b) will give 12 which is 0000 1100
```